# Bootstrap modal backdrop create model in accesseble in chrome... working in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap modal in running properly in Firefox, but there is some problem in google chrome,

If i remove following code then it is running in chrome:

```
.modal-backdrop.modal-absolute{
    position: relative;
    background-color : red;
    z-index: 940;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: #333333;
  opacity:0.8; 
 }

.modal-backdrop, 
.modal-backdrop.fade.in{
    opacity: 0.45;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1030;
    filter: alpha(opacity=45);
    background: black;

}
```

Please tell me what is error in this code

Comment: As a first step Have you tried using the "inspect element" in Chrome (right mouse button whilst over the web page.) Then click on the console tab and that will show any page errors. If there are any errors could you update and share and that will help people help you! Also, it might be worth checking Chrome Vendor Prefixes to see if any of those are relevant here.

Comment: there is no error, if i remove posotion:absolute then it is working

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing the output.

If you are using absolute positioning, Could you should use the right/left & top/bottom attributes to position the elements instead of margin?

Maybe also make sure your container (the parent of the absolute elements) has position: relative; set, so the positioning of his children (the absolute ones) will be relative to him.

Also try and search google for any one else having this issue, try searching "position: absolute issues with chrome"